# How do I properly execute the path in nextjs css or scss?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styles, styling

When I'm creating NextJS projects(i'm still practicing). It always ask me about 5 things which is

Typescript - No / Yes
ESLint - No / Yes
src / directory - No / Yes
app / directory ( I forgot just imagine it when you creating one) - No / Yes
imports '@/' - No / Yes

And I always input Yes-Yes-No-No-Yes since I know typescript and ESLint, but I don't know how the path works with CSS.

so the folder was created something like this

-pages

-public

-styles

so basically I have this in `pages/_app.tsx` right

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import '@/styles/globals.css'
```

and then in my styles I have two css which is navbar.module.css and global.module.css

but the thing is that I can make like naming module css right like pass it to the `className`'s?

So this is in my `navbar.module.css`

```
.navbar_header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 30px 50px;
}

.navbar_parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 230, 0, 0.46);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.links {
    padding: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFC27B 0%, #FFE91F 85.42%);
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And at the part of pages/navbar.tsx I pass there my `navbar.module.css`

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'
import styles from '@/styles/navbar.module.css'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.navbar_header}>
            <div className={styles.navbar_parent}>
                <Link  className={styles.links} href={'/'}>
                    <h5> 
                        Home
                    </h5>
                </Link>
                <Link  className={styles.links} href={'/authentication/auth'}>
                    <h5>
                        Sign Up / Log In
                    </h5>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Also in my pages/index.tsx I have this code

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Navbar from './navbar';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/p5.png" />
        <title> Next.JS Designing </title>
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Navbar/>
      </body>
    </>
  )
}
```

and I always get this thing. error in front of the website.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

Is there something wrong I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm the error came from `<body></body>`  that was created in the `<Navbar/>`  at the `index.tsx` hahahaha